# Should game logic be on client or server?

Tags: java, design-patterns, client-server

I'm creating a simple multiplayer turn-based game.

I can't decide where to draw the line between putting all the logic on the client or on the server.

Should the client be used just to send input to the server and print/display the responses?(This is my current solution, but seems to make the client too "stupid")

If not, how do I decide what goes on which side?

The game is very simple so I do think I could have any lag or bandwidth problems in any case.

Answer (score 2):

You should always put all the game logic you can in the server, as clientside can be modified and cheat. Never trust the client.

Answer (score 2):

Think of the server as the "game" and the client as the "player". Keep the client as minimal as possible. Restrict the client's influence on the game as much as you can. The client should really only be able to ask to do this and do that, it shouldn't be able to decided for itself what the result of a move be.

A real world example where the client behaved as the server was Halo 3 multiplayer where the game chose a player, part of the match, as the host (server).

Cons:

Players could lag switch other players and cause them to lag. Those players couldn't do anything and the host player just killed them and won the match.

Players chosen as hosts had bad internet and so everyone lagged to the point where a new host had to be selected.

If the host player left the game the match would stop and try to find another host (player) which wasn't always successful or take minutes.